# PL/SQL bulk INSERT into a table with an unknown structure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bulkinsert

Can you issue a FORALL bulk INSERT into a table with an unknown structure? That means, can you build dynamically the INSERT command in the FORALL construct without knowing the number of fields at compile time?

Number and name of fields is retrieved at runtime and stored in a collection:

```
TYPE RowType is TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);
TYPE TableType is TABLE OF RowType;
my_table TableType;
```

So at runtime my_table could be filled this way for example:

```
my_table(1)('FIELD1') = 'VALUE1A';
my_table(1)('FIELD2') = 'VALUE2A';
my_table(1)('FIELD3') = 'VALUE3A';
my_table(2)('FIELD1') = 'VALUE1B';
my_table(2)('FIELD2') = 'VALUE2B';
my_table(2)('FIELD3') = 'VALUE3B';
my_table(3)('FIELD1') = 'VALUE1C';
my_table(3)('FIELD2') = 'VALUE2C';
my_table(3)('FIELD3') = 'VALUE3C';
```

The insert statements that should be bulk executed therefore are:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES (VALUE1A,VALUE2A,VALUE3A);
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES (VALUE1B,VALUE2B,VALUE3B);
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES (VALUE1C,VALUE2C,VALUE3C);
```

**EDIT:** Do you even read the questions or you just read a couple of words in the title? The linked question asks how to bind a variable, this question asks how to bulk issue dynamic statements. Yes, there are the words 'insert' and 'table' in both questions.

Comment: *"can you build dynamically the INSERT command in the FORALL construct without knowing the number of fields at compile time?"* No.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting Data Into Table Using Execute Immediate in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074356/inserting-data-into-table-using-execute-immediate-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't dynamically build and execute a `FORALL...INSERT...` statement dynamically. You *can*, however, build up an INSERT statement dynamically of the form:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES (VALUE1A,VALUE2A,VALUE3A)
  INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES (VALUE1B,VALUE2B,VALUE3B)
  INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES (VALUE1C,VALUE2C,VALUE3C)
```

Or if the data you want to insert into your table resides in another table you might find an `INSERT...(subquery)` statement like

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME
  SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
    FROM OTHER_TABLE
    WHERE something <> something_else
```

or you might be able to use a MERGE statement similar to

```
MERGE INTO TABLENAME t
  USING (SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM OTHER_TABLE) o
    ON (t.FIELD1 = o.FIELD1)
  WHEN NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) VALUES (o.FIELD1, o.FIELD2, o.FIELD3)
```

which will do a mass insert based on the data specified in the `USING` clause and the match criteria in the `ON` predicate.

So there may be ways to do what you want but without knowing the specifics of the source of your data and how you're manipulating that data prior to inserting it into your database it's tough to say whether or not any of them would apply.

Best of luck.

Comment: Does the INSERT ALL cause a single switch between the PL/SQL engine and the SQL engine or one switch per row?

Comment: The `INSERT ALL` is a single SQL statement which is passed intact to the SQL engine.